# Use only one monitor at a time?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

How can I tell Ubuntu to automatic turn the primary screen of when I connect a secondary screen?

Case:
I have my primary monitor connected through a Display port, and sometimes I connect a tv through a HDMI port. When I do this the desktop expands with a blank desktop on the TV.

Instead I want the primary monitor to automatic turn off, and stay turned off, as long as the HDMI is connected to the TV. So that the full desktop is visible on the TV instead. And the primary monitor to turn back on, when the TV is disconnected.

Is that possible?

Comment: The dupe- link is a 100% match, but the title was not very clear :) Edited it.